# Facebook API Lead Ad webhook lead retrieval in asp.net application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

I have connected Facebook Webhook with my asp.net application successfully.
Now, When I try to to subscribe to Lead ad webhook does not trigger any post request to my call back url.

Code provided by Facebook to get data is as below.

Note this code is in PHP need to be converted in c#

```
<?php

$challenge = $_REQUEST['hub_challenge'];
$verify_token = $_REQUEST['hub_verify_token'];

if ($verify_token === 'abc123xyz') {
echo $challenge;
}

$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php:://input'), true);
error_log(print_r($input, true))
```

Unfortunately I'm not able to convert last two lines in c#.
I have referred below link.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/quickstart/webhooks-integration

Any help regarding this is greatly appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: _“Unfortunately I'm not able to convert last two lines in c#.”_ - well then I’d suggest you do some research to _find out_ how to do that in c# ... https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+how+to+read+JSON+POST

Comment: @Pravin after two years you may mark Somaraj answer as correct. since it is elaborate and works

Answer (score 4):

**Create the following class**

```
public class JsonData
{
    [JsonProperty("entry")]
    public List<Entry> Entry { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("object")]
    public string Object { get; set; }
}
public class Entry
{
    [JsonProperty("changes")]
    public List<Change> Changes { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("time")]
    public int Time { get; set; }
}

public class Change
{
    [JsonProperty("field")]
    public string Field { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public Value Value { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    [JsonProperty("ad_id")]
    public string AdId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("form_id")]
    public string FormId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("leadgen_id")]
    public string LeadGenId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("created_time")]
    public int CreatedTime { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("page_id")]
    public string PageId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("adgroup_id")]
    public string AdGroupId { get; set; }
}

public class LeadData
{
    [JsonProperty("created_time")]
    public string CreatedTime { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("field_data")]
    public List<FieldData> FieldData { get; set; }
}

public class FieldData
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("values")]
    public List<string> Values { get; set; }
}

public class LeadFormData
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("leadgen_export_csv_url")]
    public string CsvExportUrl { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("locale")]
    public string Locale { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

**In the Post action do this**

```
public void Post([FromBody] JsonData data)
    {
        try
        {
            var entry = data.Entry.FirstOrDefault();
            //Get change
            var change = entry?.Changes.FirstOrDefault();
            if (change == null) return;

            //Get lead Id
            var leadId = change.Value.LeadGenId;

            //Lead Id is used for further processing
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.TraceError($"Error >> {ex.Message} >> StackTrace {ex.StackTrace}");
        }
    }
```

for more detail refer [Facebook ASP.NET Webhook](https://github.com/somaraj/Facebook-ASP.NET-Webhook)